# consulta en Laravel con respecto a fechas

Tags: sql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Estoy en un proyecto laravel, donde ya sea por medio de DB o Eloquent, quiero hacer que se haga el conteo de una consulta la cual es la siguiente:

```
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $count = DB::table('fichas')->where('DATE(created_at)',$fecha)->count();
```

lo que hice hasta aqui es tomar el campo datetime 'created_at' para que solo agarre la fecha, pero me marca el error de que no existe la columna, entonces la verdad no se como se le haga, espero alguien me pueda ayudar

la consulta en otras palabras se podria decir que quiero que: se cuenten los registros que hay en la tabla fichas donde created_at sea igual a la fecha de hoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Laravel cuenta con un método para comparar fechas llamado `whereDate()` y lo puedes utilizar directamente con la columna `created_at` de la siguiente forma:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
$users = DB::table('fichas')->whereDate('created_at', $fecha)->get();
```

Comment: Gracias, si me sirvió ponerle el whereDate() era lo único que le faltaba a mi código

Answer (score 0):

Anexo el código con el que funciono lo que quería hacer

```
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $count = DB::table('fichas')->whereDate('created_at', $fecha)->count();
```

Lo que hace es que: de la tabla fichas cuente el número de registros existentes cuando (solo la fecha) de 'created_at' sea igual a la variable $fecha, osea que sea igual a la fecha del día de hoy.